# File Dialog Get Full Path

Tags: c#

I have a OpenFileDialog to which I just need a Full Path such e.g "C:\Users\Tshililo\example.csv". How do I get the path after selecting a file?

I've tried using `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.File.Name);` but the output is "example.csv".

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    using (var stream = ofd.File.OpenRead())
            {
      var thiname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.File.Name);
                    //var oldPath = 
      System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.File.Name);

                }
```

My expected results are "C:\Users\Tshililo\example.csv"

Comment: You are already using the `System.IO.Path` type. Check its public method list.

Comment: Use `ofd.FileName`, that already is the full path.

Comment: Where does `File.Name` come from? I'm not seeing it in the docs.

Comment: i am getting this error and i cannot access Filename ofd.File.Directory' threw an exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException'

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

From the [FileDialog.FileName docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.FileName);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8):

> The file name includes both the file path and the extension. If no files are selected, this method returns an empty string ("").

`OpenFileDialog` inherits from the `FileDialog` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might use an OpenFileDialog.

- Calling `ShowDialog()` will show the dialog and halt your program execution while the user chooses the file. After they say OK or Cancel, it resumes.
- Inspect the result of `ShowDialog()` - if it's OK then we can proceed with manipulating the file the user picked. Most critically the `.FileName` property holds the full path to the file.
- If you enabled Multiselect, then the multiple filenames are found in the `.FileNames` property. `.FileName` contains the same string as `.FileNames[0]`, and the order of names in `.FileNames` is generally the reverse of the order the user chose them. If your user is expecting some sort of ordered processing, sort the filenames manually yourself. It's unwise to attach any special meaning to the order of the filenames returned

---

```
//consider declaring this in a USING if you don't have one persistent 
//openfiledialog that you re-use in your app
//i typically keep just one OFD at class level and hide/show it repeatedly
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

//set options of ofd before show
ofd.Whatever = whatever;

if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){

  //some examples:
  //we could get the full file path the user chose
  var path = ofd.FileName; 

  //or we could delete the file
  File.Delete(ofd.FileName); //2) delete the file or..

  //or we could read the contents of the text file they picked
  var content = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName); 

  //or open it as a stream
  var stream = File.OpenStream(ofd.FileName); 

  //or we could get the directory the file is in
  var dir = Path.GetDirectory(ofd.FileName);

  //or we could ponder how deep the directory tree is
  var depth = ofd.FileName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()).Length;

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `path` in `ReadAllText` instead? I know it doesn't matter whatsoever, but having the unused variable there threw me off for a split second.

Comment: Oh, yes.. i kinda intended them to be independent demonstrations of the ofd.FileName property rather than flowing code that made sense

Comment: IMHO wrap the `ofd` into a `using` statement; `using (OpenFileDialog ofd= new OpenFileDialog())` which ensures the object properly gets disposed.

Comment: I tend to just have one OFD in my app and hide/show it as needed so I don't generally dispose, but your point is relevant in the sense that this code makes a new one, and could potentially make a new one each time if implemented poorly into a full app